# How to know a copy constructor is called?

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

Considering the example, I know that assigning one object to other, calls copy constructors, does `Line 2` also call a copy constructor here. **What are the total number of copy constructor calls made here?**

```
class Sample{ 
  public:
     void compare(Sample args){    }
};
int main(){
  Sample  s1;
  Sample  s2=s1; //Line 1
  s1.compare(s2); // Line 2
}
```

Comment: You could easily 1. use a debugger to check this, 2. add printf statements to also check this

Comment: the compare method takes Sample by value so it is a copy

Comment: You can figure this out for yourself: add a print statement to the copy constructor OR attach a debugger and set a breakpoint OR increment a counter OR look at the generated assembly on godbolt.org

Comment: A bit on terminology: **assigning** copies a value to an **already existing** value. **Copy construction** creates a **new object**. So `Sample s2 = s1;` **constructs** `s2` with the copy constructor. `Sample s2; s2 = s1;` **assigns** the value of `s1` to `s2`, with the assignment operator (`operator=`). Yes, they both use `=`, but they do two different things in two different ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the copy constructor to your class definition and see the result.

```
#include <iostream>
class Sample{ 
  public:
    Sample() = default;
    Sample( const Sample & ) { std::cout << "Sample( const Sample & )\n"; }
     void compare(Sample args){    }
};

int main(){
  Sample  s1;
  Sample  s2=s1; //Line 1
  s1.compare(s2); // Line 2
}
```

The program output is

```
Sample( const Sample & )
Sample( const Sample & )
```

If to comment the call

```
  // s1.compare(s2); // Line 2
```

then the output will be

```
Sample( const Sample & )
```